# SpriteKit - Rotate and Jump Both Ending at same Time

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, game-physics, skspritenode

**New to Sprite Kit and Game Development** i am learning by the [Following tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62049/sprite-kit-tutorial-make-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-1) @ **Raywenderlich**.

**`WHAT I AM DOING ?`**

I have implemented the Continuous Motion on the map and Gravity on the Player and i know that the rotation action can be added to the SKSpriteNode like this.

```
        SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1];

        [myPlayer runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
```

And my Player with gravity is as follows

**MSPlayer.h**

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface MSPlayer : SKSpriteNode
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint velocity;
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)delta;
@end
```

**MSPlayer.m**

```
#import "MSPlayer.h"
#import "SKTUtils.h"

@implementation MSPlayer
//2
- (instancetype)initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name {
    if (self == [super initWithImageNamed:name]) {
        self.velocity = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)delta {
    //3
    CGPoint gravity = CGPointMake(0.0, -10.0);
    //4
    CGPoint gravityStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(gravity, delta);
    //5
    self.velocity = CGPointAdd(self.velocity, gravityStep);
    CGPoint velocityStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(self.velocity, delta);
    //6
    self.position = CGPointAdd(self.position, velocityStep);
}
-(CGRect)collisionBoundingBox {
    return CGRectInset(self.frame, 2, 0);
}

@end
```

**`My Issue is`**

Now the issue is that i want the Node to be rotated and give make it jump with gravity and the rotation ends just before the Node is about to end its jump. What should be done to make both animations end at the same time?

Comment: do you simply want to end at the same time or make one jump have only one rotate animation synchronized ?

Comment: I want the rotation and the animation synchronized and end at the same time.

Comment: then you have to calculate how much time you jump will take to land ( based on gravity values ) or you can have animation of jumping up and one for landing which is easier to calculate and implement

Comment: Second option seems alot better. can you help me out in the second option?

Comment: simply start a rotate action when you jump up , and keep that till you peak , after the velocity goes in negative direction , start a landing animation. If you have to make it perfectly synchronized , you would have to calculate next frames yourself and the position and calculate how much time will the player take to reach the ground

Answer (score 0):

Write another runAction for Jumping

```
[myPlayer runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:runAction]];
```

Define runAction here.

Comment: i don't want to rotate the node continuously and also that i don't want the node to jump continuously